# After Add Data from API suddenly got classlist of undefined in Vue.Js Method

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2

I want to ask about this, I search in a lot of thread about this topic since it is a common topic but, It seems I don't quite understand where is the fail part in my code. At first, my code works fine without any problem, but when I add a data from API suddenly I got this `ClassList of undefined` even thought I already check it using if.

this is my code before Adding Any Data from API: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sara-2fy30

and this is my code after I add API Data:

Template:

```
<!-- start tab content -->
<div class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="tab_sec1">
  <div class="merchandise-item-wrapper">
    <table class="merchandise-table">
      <tr id="customWrapper">
        <td
          class="item-store"
          v-for="(merchandise, index) in merchandises"
          :key="index"
        >
          <div>
            <div
              class="portfolio-img bg-white position-relative text-center overflow-hidden"
            >
              <img
                class="merchandise-img"
                :src="
                  merchandise.Thumbnail
                    ? merchandise.Thumbnail
                    : 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300'
                "
              />
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top: 3vh;">
              <div class="portfolio-hover-main text-center">
                <div class="portfolio-hover-box align-middle">
                  <div
                    class="portfolio-hover-content position-relative"
                  >
                    <div class="row text-left">
                      <div class="col-10 col-md-11 col-lg-4">
                        <p class="merchandise-category">
                          Mechandise Code
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                        <p class="merchandise-category">:</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7">
                        <p class="merchandise-code">
                          {{ merchandise.Name }} ({{
                            merchandise.ProductCode
                          }})
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row text-left">
                      <div class="col-10 col-md-11 col-lg-4">
                        <p class="merchandise-category">
                          Description
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                        <p class="merchandise-category">:</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7">
                        <p
                          class="merchandise-text number-of-lines-5"
                        >
                          {{ merchandise.Description }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row text-left">
                      <div class="col-10 col-md-11 col-lg-4">
                        <p class="merchandise-category">Price</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                        <p class="merchandise-category">:</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7">
                        <p class="merchandise-price">
                          {{ formattedPrice(merchandise.Price) }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end tab content -->
```

this is my method:

```
data() {
  return {
    loading: true,
    statusRelease: false,
    totalItems: 9,
    currentPosition: 0,
    maxPosition: 0,
    multiplier: 0,
    imgScaller: 0,
    originalLength: 0,
    prevStatus: true,
    nextStatus: true,
    intervalStatus: true,
    merchandises: []
  };
},

methods: {
  toNextSection() {
    let next = document.getElementById("merchandise");
    next.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  },

  formattedPrice(price) {
    return formatCurrency(price);
  },

  itemSlider() {
    let autoScroller = document.getElementById("customWrapper");
    let item = autoScroller.getElementsByTagName("td");

    this.maxPosition = -1 * autoScroller.offsetWidth;

    if (this.intervalStatus) {
      if (this.multiplier === this.originalLength * 2) {
        item[this.imgScaller].classList.remove("active");
        this.multiplier = 0;
        this.imgScaller = 0;

        for (let i; i < this.originalLength; i++) {
          autoScroller.removeChild(autoScroller.children[i]);
        }
        item[this.imgScaller + 1].classList.add("active");
      }

      if (item[this.imgScaller].classList != undefined) {
        this.currentPosition =
          -1 * item[this.imgScaller].offsetWidth * this.multiplier;
        autoScroller.style.transform = `translateX(${this.currentPosition}px)`;
        autoScroller.style.transition = `0.5s`;
      }

      if (this.imgScaller - 1 !== -1 && this.imgScaller !== 0) {
        let firstSlide = item[this.imgScaller - 1];
        let cloneFirst = firstSlide.cloneNode(true);
        autoScroller.appendChild(cloneFirst);
      }

      if (this.imgScaller) {
        item[this.imgScaller + 1].classList.add("active");
      }
      if (this.imgScaller - 1 !== -1) {
        item[this.imgScaller].classList.remove("active");
        item[this.imgScaller - 1].classList.remove("active");
      }

      this.multiplier++;
      this.imgScaller++;

      setTimeout(this.itemSlider, 3000);
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i].classList) {
          item[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
      }
    }
  },

  removeCells() {
    let autoScroller = document.getElementById("customWrapper");
    let item = autoScroller.getElementsByTagName("td");
    this.originalLength = item.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.originalLength; i++) {
      if (item[i]) {
        autoScroller.removeChild(item[i]);
      }
    }
  },

  getMerchandise() {
    getMerchandise({
      Limit: 16,
      Page: 1,
      OrderBy: "Name",
      OrderType: "ASC",
      PublishStatus: true
    })
      .then(({ data: { data, errors } }) => {
        if (errors && errors[0]) {
          throw Error(
            errors[0].message ? errors[0].message : "Unknown Error"
          );
        }

        this.merchandises = data.item;
        this.originalLength = this.merchandises.length;
        if (this.originalLength != 0) {
          this.itemSlider();
        }

        this.loading = false;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("getMerchandise => getMerchandiseFunction : ", e);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.getMerchandise();
}
```

If it looks so long, You can only focus in this part:

```
methods: {
  itemSlider() {
    let autoScroller = document.getElementById("customWrapper");
    let item = autoScroller.getElementsByTagName("td");

    this.maxPosition = -1 * autoScroller.offsetWidth;

    if (this.intervalStatus) {
      if (this.multiplier === this.originalLength * 2) {
        item[this.imgScaller].classList.remove("active");
        this.multiplier = 0;
        this.imgScaller = 0;

        for (let i; i < this.originalLength; i++) {
          autoScroller.removeChild(autoScroller.children[i]);
        }
        item[this.imgScaller + 1].classList.add("active");
      }

      if (item[this.imgScaller].classList != undefined) {
        this.currentPosition =
          -1 * item[this.imgScaller].offsetWidth * this.multiplier;
        autoScroller.style.transform = `translateX(${this.currentPosition}px)`;
        autoScroller.style.transition = `0.5s`;
      }

      if (this.imgScaller - 1 !== -1 && this.imgScaller !== 0) {
        let firstSlide = item[this.imgScaller - 1];
        let cloneFirst = firstSlide.cloneNode(true);
        autoScroller.appendChild(cloneFirst);
      }

      if (this.imgScaller) {
        item[this.imgScaller + 1].classList.add("active");
      }
      if (this.imgScaller - 1 !== -1) {
        item[this.imgScaller].classList.remove("active");
        item[this.imgScaller - 1].classList.remove("active");
      }

      this.multiplier++;
      this.imgScaller++;

      setTimeout(this.itemSlider, 3000);
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i].classList) {
          item[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
      }
    }
  },

  removeCells() {
    let autoScroller = document.getElementById("customWrapper");
    let item = autoScroller.getElementsByTagName("td");
    this.originalLength = item.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.originalLength; i++) {
      if (item[i]) {
        autoScroller.removeChild(item[i]);
      }
    }
  },

  getMerchandise() {
    getMerchandise({
      Limit: 16,
      Page: 1,
      OrderBy: "Name",
      OrderType: "ASC",
      PublishStatus: true
    })
      .then(({ data: { data, errors } }) => {
        if (errors && errors[0]) {
          throw Error(
            errors[0].message ? errors[0].message : "Unknown Error"
          );
        }

        this.merchandises = data.item;
        this.originalLength = this.merchandises.length;
        if (this.originalLength != 0) {
          this.itemSlider();
        }

        this.loading = false;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("getMerchandise => getMerchandiseFunction : ", e);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.getMerchandise();
}
```

can someone help me to solve this? I'm confused as how can I solved this, since this problem appear after I add data from API. The data it self, I can successfully get it, and it looks like this:

[image: The Data I Got From API]

this is error that I got:

[image: Error About ClassList of Undefined]

Can Someone Help me to solve this?